# 301 permanent redirect in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to PHP,
This is not working when i redirect in php: `<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen($file->getNextDownloadPageLink()); ?>`

What's wrong?

In JavaScript, It works:

```
<script>
window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen($file->getNextDownloadPageLink()); ?>");
</script>
```

But when i convert my javascript to php (because i want a permanent redirect and i cant do it in javascript), it doesn't work.

```
// Permanent 301 redirection
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen($file->getNextDownloadPageLink()); ?>);");
exit();
```

Thank You!

Comment: Check your PHP error log for "Headers already sent" warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Use concatenation instead of `<?php echo ...` inside PHP:

```
// Permanent 301 redirection
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=" . validation::safeOutputToScreen($file->getNextDownloadPageLink()) );
exit();
```

Comment: It doesn't redirect users, it just shows a blank page :(

Comment: Do you have error/warning display enabled to show you what might have gone wrong? This code alone should redirect, is there other code/HTML before that? Does the URL change in the address bar? Did you check your PHP error log for "Headers already sent" warnings as Barmar suggested? Or any other error?